# If a value being observed by KVO changes twice in a short amount of time, what will happen in observeValueForKeyPath()?

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, swift, key-value-observing

From my understanding, since I do not use a separate thread for my KVO (observeValueForKeyPath in Swift), when a value I'm observing changes, observeValueForKeyPath() will be called with the same thread. What I'm not sure is that say I'm in the middle of observeValueForKeyPath(), then the value changes again, what will happen? Will my current execution be interrupt, and I start from the beginning of observeValueForKeyPath() again? In this case, do I resume to the interrupted previous observeValueForKeyPath() once the latter observeValueForKeyPath() finishes? In this case, I suppose it causes a race condition if I'm manipulating data in observeValueForKeyPath().
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVO is really cool.  What's actually happening (as found by [mike ash](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html)) is that the runtime will subclass your **observed** object, and override the **setter** for the property that is being observed.  The overridden setter has extra instructions that will eventually explicitly call `-observeValueForKey` for the **observing** object.

So what happens if you change the value at the specified keypath from **within** `-observeValueForKey`, you'll just end up with the `-observeValueForKey` message being sent to the **observed** (the same) object.  So it as you say, your current execution will be interrupted, a handful of KVO-related stack frames will be placed on your call stack, and if everything resolves properly you will continue along like normal.

Of course the thing to be weary of is if inside of `-observeValueForKey` for an object you **always** kick off a notification to the same object.  You will end up in an infinite loop and your app will crash.

And I wouldn't call what you're describing as a race condition because at no point are two objects trying to read/write an object at the same time.  You just have to be weary of the **order** in which you are reading and writing, as that may not be what you expect

Comment: @A O yea you are right it's not a race condition. It's just that, suppose in observeValueForKey I have an array of double I want to manipulate, and while I haven't finished manipulating all of them, it's possible that another observeValueForKey will happen. And this will cause the values to be incorrect at the end. This problem will happen right?

Comment: Correct.  You just need to make sure that you aren't kicking off KVO notifications within your `-observeValueForKey` unless you explicitly wanted to.  The way to get around this is to set the backing `ivar` (e.g, `_myProperty`) instead of calling the synthesized setter (e.g, `self.myProperty`).  By setting the `ivar` directly you circumvent that overridden setter the runtime generates to kick KVO notifications